# 3D models slow to load, missing textures

Tags: google-earth

The 3D models in Google Earth 7.0.1.8244 are slow to load (1-3 minutes) and once they do are missing textures. The only models that look fine are the trees.

Based on the tips in this [three year old thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/pHIRZevLPWs%5B101-125-false%5D), I have tried switching between Direct X and OpenGL, compressed and uncompressed textures, and those combinations, but that didn't help at all. I'm not willing to try the suggestion of limiting RAM to 3 GB, but that had mixed results anyway.

I have a 30 megabit connection to the net, and can see there's not much network activity from Google Earth in Task Manager. I'm using Windows 8 with a Core i5 and GTX 570.

The RAM cache is set to 1024 MB and the disk cache set to 4096 MB.

[image: 3D building models]

*Cathedral of Saint John the Divine as seen in Google Earth*
[image: Same scene in Google Maps with Google Earth Plugin]

*About the same scene as above, in Google Maps with the Google Earth plugin for Chrome*